# ansible mssql issue ( ansible-galaxy module)

Tags: sql-server, ansible, ansible-galaxy, ansible-collections

I am trying to query the sql server from ansible controller. Using the ansible-galaxy in built collections. The server is accessible and WINRM is working. But still I am getting the below error message. Can anyone suggest what is the issue ? TIA

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel//collections/community/general/mssql_script_module.html

### YML file.

- hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  collections:

  - community.general
    tasks:
  - name: Check DB connection
    community.general.mssql_script:
    login_user: "testadmin"
    login_password: "test@12345"
    login_host: "xxxxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS"
    login_port: "1433"
    db: master
    script: "SELECT 1"

Error message

fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"module_stderr": "Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:4 char:21\r\n+ def _ansiballz_main():\r\n+                     ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:13 char:27\r\n+     except (AttributeError, OSError):\r\n+                           ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nAt line:15 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:15 char:30\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                              ~~~~~~~~~\r\nUnexpected token 'scriptdir' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:15 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing closing ')' in expression.\r\nAt line:15 char:39\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                       ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:15 char:40\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                        ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:7\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:30\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                              ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:22 char:25\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                         ~\r\nThe '<' operator is reserved for future use.\r\nNot all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again."\r\nAt line:10 char:1\r\n+ $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException\r\n \r\nThe expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command \r\nname, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.\r\nAt line:11 char:2\r\n+ &$exec_wrapper\r\n+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression\r\n ",
"module_stdout": "",
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
"rc": 1
}

Comment: Aside... `login_host: "xxxxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS" login_port: "1433"` seems like an unlikely combination. Unless you've specifically reconfigured the Server Protocols in SQL Server Configuration Manager, the default `MSSQLSERVER` instance is usually listening on 1433 and SQL Express will be on a dynamic high-numbered port (i.e.: somewhere in the 49152-65535 range).

Comment: `Missing argument in parameter list` sounds like a scripting error rather than a communications problem. Have you used Ansible Lint to check your file?

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning , For first issue I have changed the port value to 1433 in SQL Server.      For Second issue , the scripting is done in visual studio with proper YAML format.